# Password Regex with ANY THREE combination but no spaces

Tags: java, regex

Ensure Password meets the following Criteria

- Length: 8-32 characters
- Password must contain atleast 3 of the following: Uppercase, Lowercase, Number, Symbol
- Password must not contain Spaces
- Password Characters allowed:

  ```
  !@#$%^*()_+Aa1~`-={}[]|\:;"',.?/
  ```

I tried:

```
^.*(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])^(?!.*[&])(?=.*[!@#$%^*()_+Aa1~`\-={}[\]|\:;"',.?/])\S{8,32}$
```

I have written this Regex, But enforces One uppercase letter which Should not be the case.......It should accept any three combinations of Uppercase, Lowercase, Numbers, Symbols:

```
!@#$%^*()_+Aa1~`-={}[]|\:;"',.?/
```

The regex limit limit 255 characters. Any suggestions help on this please.

Comment: Sorry if I ask, but is this necessary? A short password with an high variability of characters is still a weak password, while a long password with only letters is stronger

Comment: That's the requirement. I cannot change that. Thanks for asking:)

Comment: Which flavor is it?

Comment: I guess so. Of course you can always point out that the requirement is wrong. This is a good argument: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Which flavor is it? Enforced on the UI...Java

Comment: Are you sure it's Java and not Javascript (if it's enforced on the UI?)

Comment: `.*[a-z]` -> `(?:.*[a-z]){3}`

Comment: Not working. It's still enforcing One uppercase.

Comment: Example of Match Password as per requirements: stack12*

Comment: @Roja, it is a general advice for any of your lookahead.

Comment: Is there a hard requirement on only using a single regular expression? It seems like it would be far simpler to write a regular expression for each requirement, and then AND the results together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?=.*[!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[a-z].*)[\w!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-]{8,32}$|
^(?=.*[!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-].*)(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[a-z].*)[\w!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-]{8,32}$|
^(?=.*[!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*\d.*)[\w!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-]{8,32}$|
^(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=.*[a-z].*)[\w!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;"',.?\[\]\/-]{8,32}$
```

See [LiveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/mD3wT7/2)

---

If you want a bit more of flexibility you can use this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Dummy{
   public static void main(String []args){
      String password = "aaaZZZ111";
      String specials = "!@#$%^*()_+~`={}|:;\"',.?\\[\\]\\/-";
      String uppercase = "A-Z";
      String lowercase = "a-z";
      String numbers = "\\d";
      String all = specials + uppercase + lowercase + numbers;
      int min = 8;
      int max = 32;

      String regex =
         "^" + lookahead(specials) +  lookahead(uppercase) + lookahead(lowercase) + "[" + all + "]{"+ min +"," + max + "}$|" +
         "^" + lookahead(specials) +  lookahead(uppercase) + lookahead(numbers) + "[" + all + "]{"+ min +"," + max + "}$|" +
         "^" + lookahead(specials) +  lookahead(lowercase) + lookahead(numbers) + "[" + all + "]{"+ min +"," + max + "}$|" +
         "^" + lookahead(uppercase) + lookahead(lowercase) + lookahead(numbers) + "[" + all + "]{"+ min +"," + max + "}$";

      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);

      Matcher m = r.matcher(password);
      if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println("OK");
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }

   public static String lookahead(String input) {
      return "(?=.*[" + input + "].*)";
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we have shorter version of this by any case?

Comment: it's accepting spaces and symbol  & which should not be

Comment: Works fine now. Please share if you have any shorter version of the Regex.

Comment: @Roja not shorter but cleaner

Comment: I just realised that we have character limit for Regex which is 255. So the longer version should not exceed 255.

Comment: @Roja. Or you edit your question with *real* context or I'm off.

Comment: @Ros This is not *context*, you just copy/pasted your comment to the question. Context is tell us **why** your need it to be 255 char long. And if it really have to be this short, you'll never make it with a regex.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I will use the longer version of Regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:[A-Z]()|[a-z]()|[0-9]()|[!@#$%^*()_+~`={}\[\]|\:;"',.?/-]())+$(?:\1\2\3|\1\2\4|\1\3\4|\2\3\4)
```

In more readable form:

```
^
(?:
   [A-Z] () |
   [a-z] () |
   [0-9] () |
   [!@#$%^*()_+~`={}\[\]|\\:;"',.?/-] ()
)+
$
(?:
   \1\2\3 |
   \1\2\4 |
   \1\3\4 |
   \2\3\4
)
```

What I'm doing is using empty capturing groups as check boxes, tallying which kinds of characters were seen over the course of the match.  So, for example, if there's no uppercase letter in the string, group #1 never participates in the match, so `\1` won't succeed at the end.  Unless all three other groups do participate, the match will fail.

Be aware that this technique doesn't work in all flavors.  In JavaScript, for example, a backreference to an empty group always succeeds, even if the group didn't participate in the match.